# C# Threading - an array of threads, where each thread contains a form with an image

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, forms

I have an array of five threads. Each thread contains the same form, each form is put on to the screen in a different location (still working on that method :P).

I am trying to have each form load its contents (an image) before the other forms have finishing being placed. At the moment this works for the first form, but the others are blank or disappear :P

Originally each form would be placed but the method would need to finish before all the forms contents were displayed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

```
public partial class TrollFrm : Form
{
    int number = 0;

    public TrollFrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        startThreads();

    }

    private void TrollFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void TrollFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    public void startThreads()
    {
        Thread[] ThreadArray = new Thread[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ThreadArray[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(createForm));

            ThreadArray[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void createForm()
    {
        Form frm = new TrollChildFrm();

        Random randomX = new Random();

        Random randomY = new Random();

        number++;

        int xValue;

        int yValue;

        if (number % 2 == 0)    //number is even.
        {
            xValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomX.Next(1, 1920))) + 200;

            yValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomY.Next(1, 1080))) - 200;
        }

        else    //number is not even.
        {
            xValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomX.Next(1, 1920))) - 200;

            yValue = (Convert.ToInt32(randomY.Next(1, 1080))) + 200;
        }

        frm.Show();

        frm.Location = new Point(xValue, yValue);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: ><((((º> here is your fish ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forms are not displaying correctly because they are not running on a thread with a message loop. The general rule is that all UI element accesses must occur on the main UI thread.

Since you have a call to `Thread.Sleep(1000)` I am going to assume that you want to wait 1 second between the initial display of each form. In that case I would use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` who's `Tick` event will call `createForm` directly. Enable the timer, let 5 `Tick` events come through, and then disable the timer. I see no need to create any threads at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your forms aren't displaying is because you are running inside one method on the main UI thread. Instead, you could create a method that spawns a new form and launch that at certain intervals on another thread (making sure the form handling is done on the main UI thread). So you could do something like:

```
(Pseudo Code)
private const int TIME_THRESHOLD = 100;

int mElapsedTime = 0;
Timer mTimer = new Timer();

.ctor
{
    mTimer.Elapsed += mTimer_Elapsed;
}

private void mTimer_Elapsed(...)
{
    mElapsedTime++;

    if (mElapsedTime >= TIME_THRESHOLD)
    {
        mElapsedTime = 0;

        SpawnForm();
    }
}

private void SpawnForm()
{
    // Make sure your running on the UI thread
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(SpawnForm));
        return;
    }

    // ... spawn the form ...
}
```

This is just an example of what I was proposing - it would not look exactly like this in the code, but this should give you an idea of the execution steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Thread.Sleep(1000) in this manner

Caller section

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ThreadArray[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(createForm));
        ThreadArray[i].Start();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Also in the method that executing the work for the thread.

```
    while(!something)
    {
         Thread.Sleep(1000)
    }
```